# What could you replace 'including' with when it's followed by an extreme example of something?

Tags: phrase-request

How do you translate the Russian phrase 'вплоть до'? It's like "including" but is followed by some extreme example of what is mentioned earlier. Something like

> He was ready to execute any order, [вплоть до] a murder.

'Even as much as'?

Comment: Just *...even a murder* sounds better to me, though the sentence is awkward for another reason - *a murder* is not *an order* in itself. It would be *even one to commit a murder*, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase that comes to mind is **up to and including**, which emphasizes that it covers the end point and everything in between.

For instance,

> [The appropriate 'script' can portray the most inhuman act (up to, and including genocide)](https://books.google.com/books?id=a0ogBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR9&dq=%22up%20to%20and%20including%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjC_uacobPvAhUEFVkFHdacAD84FBDoATACegQICRAC)

> [The administrator can take a wide range of actions on your device, up to and including remotely wiping it of all its content](https://books.google.com/books?id=-_LYBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA221&dq=%22up%20to%20and%20including%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD25P1oLPvAhX8FVkFHeRhDSg4ChDoATAIegQIBxAC)

Comment: Can I simply say 'up to'?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev  Just "up to murder" sounds like it might mean "up to but **not** including murder."

Answer (score 1):

The most common word to use is probably "even". Like, "He would do anything for the cause, even commit murder."

"Including" is also perfectly good. "He would do anything for the cause, including commit murder."

Strangdon's suggestion of "up to and including" is also good and commonly used. A little wordier, obviously, which could be good or could be bad depending on the desired rhythm of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I support other answers, and there's one more idiom that came to my mind, which might be appropriate in this context:

### [go so far/as far as to do something](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/go-so-far-as-far-as-to-do-something)

> He cares for his family, but **he would go as far as to harm** people to keep that family.

> Edward was as radical as his father and **would go as far as to kill** a member of a Royalist household in the name of religion.

> Maybe **we didn't go as far as to kill** someone, but how many of us have actually pulled a knife, bat, or some form of weapon during a spat with our mate?

> She tells him that **she would go as far as to murder** her own new-born child.